# Resize Xcode window on Mac OS

Tags: xcode, macos

I am a new mac user and I would like to know if you that use Xcode are able to resize the UI window as you like. On my macbook pro retina Xcode window has a width of minimum 60% of the screen. I cannot shrink it further than this. It is strange since there is a lot of unused window space(about 40% of the Xcode window).

I am using Spectacle app that allows me to split the screen. I know that I can switch between desktops but I like to have the documentation always visible.

It also happens in iTunes, but I don't care. The important thing is to have a good programming environment.

Please can you tell me if there is any solution? In both windows and linux GUI I never experienced a fixed minimum size such annoying... But 60% hardcoded is just too much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The minimum window width is due to the Xcode toolbar. If you disable the toolbar you can have a slimmer window, but then you don't have a toolbar :(

to hide the toolbar you can right-click it and select "hide toolbar".

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it works with no toolbar. It seems that there is no way to customise the toolbar according to http://pilky.me/view/16 . In theory removing few items from it should be enough.

Comment: This is an old question, but I'd like to add that I wanted my console in separate window so it's vertical and easier to read, and you can remove the toolbar on that separate debug window and have the toolbar in your project.